# JSON String to C# List Remove one node

Tags: json, c#-4.0, generic-list

I have a JSon string that looks like the below

```
[{"status":"success","filename":"1.jpg","mainpic":"false","fullurl":"../userimages/1.jpg"},{"status":"success","filename":"2.jpg","mainpic":"false","fullurl":"../userimages/2.jpg"}]
```

So what I am needing to do is to parse that into an a generic list so that I can remove the nodes that I don't want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many solutions in .Net to deserialize JSON:

DataContractJsonSerializer http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer.aspx

JavaScriptSerializer http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer(v=VS.100).aspx

Json.Net http://json.codeplex.com/

Any of them can help you solve your question, but i prefer Json.Net as the most powerfull